# What is the role of the following files during boot from live usb?

Tags: boot, live-usb, uefi, secure-boot

- /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-29-generic
- /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-29-generic.efi.signed
- /usr/lib/linux/vmlinuz-3.8.0-29-generic.efi.signature
- /casper/vmlinuz.efi
- /cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed
- /casper/initrd.lz
- /EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI
- /EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi

Answer (score 0):

These files are being used to boot up the system.  Basically, to run an OS, the system needs to access kernel and to load OS into virtual memory to start operation in booting up the system.  GRUB is the 'engine' that is responsible in loading up all of data in order to boot up the system.

With Linux structure, a small portion of hard drive is being used for booting up only.  After the OS is being loaded and sync-ed with kernel (BIOS of your motherboard), it'll then mount your main partition where / and /home/yourusername is located.

typical structure that is common among Ubuntuians:

sda1 master disk (where your GRUB resides) - classified as "primary partition"

sda2 as extended partition.  you will never see that partition because it is a "box" that hold "boxes" such as your sda5 - thus classified as "extended partition".

sda5 as logical partition where all of your main directory resides in. (i.e. / or /home/yourusername or such).

These structures are what enable Linux to operate.  So, these files above are what control and assist in swapping and mounting these partitions so that way your OS can be loaded.

But, just a word of caution - these files are not something you would want to mess with, otherwise you might may need to revisit the re-installation of system, who knows.

Comment: Thank you. I could not boot Ubuntu installed on my computer due to confusing battle between grub2 and windows boot manager. So i was curious about what important file were the bootloaders not able to find.